# Mongoose GroupBy queries

Tags: mongoose

My Mongo collection currently looks like below:

```
[ {model: 'audi' ,    rent-date: '05-15-15'  },
{model: 'ford' ,      rent-date: '06-15-15' },
{model: 'nissan' ,    rent-date: '05-15-15' },
{model: 'toyota' ,     rent-date: '05-15-15'  },
{model: 'audi' , rent-date: '05-15-15'  },
{model: 'audi' , rent-date: '05-15-15'  },
{model: 'nissan' , rent-date: '05-15-15'  },
...
...
    ]
```

I am using mongoose to query.

Goal is to get results that resemble below

```
{ 'model' : 'audi', count: '20'
  'model: : 'nissan' , count: '30'
..
 }
```

i.e count the number of times a particular model appears in the collection.

so far I have:

```
var query = Model.aggregate.group({_id: 'model'}, count: {$sum: 1});

query.exec();
```

The above does not work though.

Answer (score 1):

```
   test.aggregate(
       [
          {
            $group: model,
               count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
          }
       ]
    )
```

Comment: not looking for only audi or nissan.. I am looking for a count on all models

Answer (score 1):

Below query worked for me:

```
Model.aggregate([
{
  $group: {
      _id: '$model', // model is the name of the field.. but we have to use $model
       count: {$sum : 1}
  }
}
])
```